# Is this economical?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Just wanting to see if there is a better way to do the following(there is always a better way for everything) because it does delay the application when loading due the amount of data.

I want to fill an array of records with data I have stored in csv file, I currently have it fixed length for the array but will later make it dynamic so I can add to the csv file.

```
    type
          TStarCoords = Packed record
            szSystem: String[40];
            fCoordX: Single;
            fCoordY: Single;
            fCoordZ: Single;
          end;

    SystemCoords: Array [0 .. 22379] of TStarCoords;

Const
SYSTEMS = 'Data\Systems.csv';
```

I then fill the array on the oncreate event

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  szFile, sRecord: string;
  Row, Index, i: Integer;
  slList: TStringList;
begin

  szFile := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + SYSTEMS;

  if FileExists(szFile) then
    try
      slList := TStringList.Create;
      slList.LoadFromFile(szFile);

      for Row := 0 to slList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        sRecord := slList[Row];

        index := Pos(',', sRecord);
        if index > 0 then
        begin
          SystemCoords[Row].szSystem := Copy(sRecord, 1, index - 1);
          Delete(sRecord, 1, index);
        end;

        index := Pos(',', sRecord);
        if index > 0 then
        begin
          SystemCoords[Row].fCoordX := StrToFloat(Copy(sRecord, 1, index - 1));
          Delete(sRecord, 1, index);
        end;

        index := Pos(',', sRecord);
        if index > 0 then
        begin
          SystemCoords[Row].fCoordY := StrToFloat(Copy(sRecord, 1, index - 1));
          Delete(sRecord, 1, index);
        end;

        SystemCoords[Row].fCoordZ := StrToFloat(sRecord);
      end;
    finally
      slList.Free;
    end;

  for i := Low(SystemCoords) to High(SystemCoords) do
  begin
    cbSystem.Items.Add(SystemCoords[i].szSystem);
  end;
end;
```

As you can see I am using "Pos" function to parse the csv file and also loop the array at the end to add the Star name to a combobox, Is there a more economical way of doing this?

Any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: Describing your csv data structure would be helpful

Comment: Sorry I thought the code made it clear, each line in the csv file looks like "System Name, X coords, Y Coords, Z Coords" using the comma to separate each field. an example ....

Comment: Yes of course. But please tell us what do you expect in this comma separated structure. Someone, for example, will expect data in the following order *name1,email1,name2,email2 ...*

Comment: HYEL YE,122,12.375,45.75
HYEL YEH,-96.281,0.625,-86.28
HYELOBO DI,86.468,-131.188,148.28
HYLDEKAGATI,19.25,-64.531,-1.562  

above is an example from the file, each line has a different system with different coords X,Y,Z I use this to calculate distance between each system which can be chosen from a combobox. I am using csv as it seems to be easier to implement rather than a database

Comment: Be careful of premature optimization. Don't worry about economical/optimal. Write your code first. Run it. Is it fast enough? You're done. If it's not, profile and that will help guide you as to where the problem is.

Comment: @Departure You're loading the whole file into memory and parsing it each time rather than using SQLite to store the star coordinates and accessing the data as needed? The difference between CSV and database is going to be far greater than tweaks to CSV parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others said, probably the majority of the time is spent populating the combo.

In my opinion, when dealing with big updates of a `TStrings` the [`BeginUpdate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStrings.BeginUpdate) / [`EndUpdate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStrings.EndUpdate) technique proposed by the [Jens Borrisholt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339366/is-this-economical/33339947#33339947) constitutes a valid approach.

---

As a minor issue, if your application is the only which writes and reads the data and neither machines nor humans care about the CSV format, you might consider to store the records adopting a different file format, using the [`BlockRead`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.BlockRead) and [`BlockWrite`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.BlockWrite) functions.

```
type
  TStarCoords = record
    szSystem: string[40];
    fCoordX,
    fCoordY,
    fCoordZ: Single;
  end;
```

. . .

```
const
  CFILENAME = '<your path to some file .dat>';
```

Reading the data:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  lstStarCoords: TList<TStarCoords>;
  f: File;
  starCoords: TStarCoords;
begin
  lstStarCoords := TList<TStarCoords>.Create;
  try

    AssignFile(f, CFILENAME);
    Reset(f, SizeOf(TStarCoords));
    try
      while not Eof(f) do begin
        BlockRead(f, starCoords, 1);
        lstStarCoords.Add(starCoords);
      end;
    finally
      CloseFile(f);
    end;

    cbSystem.Items.BeginUpdate;
    for starCoords in lstStarCoords do
      cbSystem.Items.Add(starCoords.szSystem);
    cbSystem.Items.EndUpdate;

  finally
    lstStarCoords.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Writing the data:

```
procedure TForm1.WriteStarCoords;
var
  lstStarCoords: TList<TStarCoords>;
  f: File;
  starCoords: TStarCoords;
  i: Integer;
begin
  lstStarCoords := TList<TStarCoords>.Create;
  try

    //let's insert 5k new items
    for i:=1 to 5000 do begin
      with starCoords do begin
        szSystem := 'HYEL YE';
        fCoordX := 122;
        fCoordY := 12.375;
        fCoordZ := 45.75;
      end;
      lstStarCoords.Add(starCoords);
    end;

    AssignFile(f, CFILENAME);
    Rewrite(f, SizeOf(TStarCoords));
    try
      for starCoords in lstStarCoords do
        BlockWrite(f, starCoords, 1);
    finally
      CloseFile(f);
    end;

  finally
    lstStarCoords.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

**EDIT**: example using pointers to store the record information directly in the `cbSystem` component.

This approach is a little more "dangerous" since it allocates memory which has to be manually freed but allows to avoid the usage of a `TDictionary` to pair the `TStarCoords.szSystem` with the corresponding record.

Declare a new type which points to the `TStarCoords` record:

```
type
  PStarCoords = ^TStarCoords;
```

Reading the data:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  lstStarCoords: TStringList;
  f: File;
  starCoords: PStarCoords;
begin
  ClearCbSystem;

  lstStarCoords := TStringList.Create(False);
  {another minor enhancement:
   since lstStarCoords does not own any TObject which needs to be freed
   the OwnsObjects property of the TStringList can be set to False
   in order to avoid some code to be execute in some method like Clear and Delete}
  try

    lstStarCoords.BeginUpdate;

    AssignFile(f, CFILENAME);
    Reset(f, SizeOf(TStarCoords));
    try
      while not Eof(f) do begin
        New(starCoords);
        BlockRead(f, starCoords^, 1);
        lstStarCoords.AddObject(starCoords^.szSystem, TObject(starCoords));
      end;
    finally
      CloseFile(f);
    end;

    lstStarCoords.EndUpdate;

    cbSystem.Items.Assign(lstStarCoords);
  finally
    lstStarCoords.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Clearing the list with `cbSystem.Clear` does not automatically dispose the underlying pointers which have to be manually freed. Use the `ClearCbSystem` procedure everytime the `cbSystem` list has to be cleared:

```
procedure TForm1.ClearCbSystem;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  cbSystem.Items.BeginUpdate;
  for i := cbSystem.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do
    Dispose(PStarCoords(cbSystem.Items.Objects[i]));
  cbSystem.Clear;
  cbSystem.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

When the form is destroyed, a call to the `ClearCbSystem` procedure ensures the pointers are disposed before the `cbSystem` component is freed by the application itself:

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClearCbSystem;
end;
```

Comment: I will try this out tonight and see if its any faster, thanks for your suggestions and ideas, I should have used TList to start with instead of an array. And no the format of data doesn't matter, the program is for myself as I am a hobbyist nothing more

Comment: In a real case you should consider to replace `TList<string>` with `TDictionary<string, TStarCoords>` - see the Jens Borrisholt's solution -  or `lstStarCoords.AddObject` to match the item selected in the list with the underlying record. On the other hand, `lstStarCoords.AddObject` introduces some new challange since a pointer must be used instead of the record

Comment: The biggest speed-up you would surely get by reading the whole file into memory in one go. `file` really should be kept in the previous millenium. Using a file stream you could read all data in one go (or in buffer size chunks) but still process it record by record.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look very efficient.

- Allocating a fixed length global array looks poor. Use a dynamic array of length determined at runtime.
- Short strings are not recommended. Don't use them in modern programming. They are legacy and don't handle Unicode.
- Don't pack records. That results in misaligned data.
- There seems to be far more heap allocations that are needed. Avoid `Delete` if you can.
- Loading into a string list won't be efficient. Use a line reader based approach for speed. Delphi's built in class though is rubbish. If you want speed and effective use of memory, roll your own.
- Probably the bulk of the time is spent populating the combo! Adding 22380 items to a combo will take a very long time. Don't do that. If the data set is smaller, only add as many items as there are in the data. Otherwise, use the virtual paradigm in your UI control.

Your next step though is to work out where the bottleneck is. We can only guess because we are missing so much information. We don't know if the data is static, how big it is, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions I will recode this and make changes based on your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TStringlist` for the parsing of the line. In the following I assume that you have you elements seperated by a comma.

Since you are putting the string representation of you records into a combobox I assunme you later on in your program needs to go the other way: Find a TStarCoords from string. Given that I woyls recoment you putting your elements in a `TDictionary` instread og a Array.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Generics.Collections, StdCtrls;

type
  TStarCoords = packed record
    szSystem: string[40];
    fCoordX: Single;
    fCoordY: Single;
    fCoordZ: Single;
  end;
const
  SYSTEMS = 'Data\Systems.csv';

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    SystemCoords: TDictionary<string, TStarCoords>;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  StarCoord: TStarCoords;
begin
  if not SystemCoords.TryGetValue(ComboBox1.Text, StarCoord) then
    exit; //todo : Make some error handling

  Caption := FloatToStr(StarCoord.fCoordX);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Lines, Elements: TStringlist;
  Line: string;
  SystemCoord: TPair<string, TStarCoords>;
begin
  if not FileExists(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + SYSTEMS) then
    exit; //todo: Some error handling

  SystemCoords := TDictionary<string, TStarCoords > .Create;
  Lines := TStringlist.Create;
  Elements := TStringlist.Create;
  Elements.LineBreak := ',';
  try
    for Line in Lines do
    begin
      Elements.Text := Line;

      SystemCoord.Key := Elements[0];
      with SystemCoord.Value do
      begin
        szSystem := string(Elements[0]);
        fCoordX := StrToFloat(Elements[1]);
        fCoordY := StrToFloat(Elements[2]);
        fCoordZ := StrToFloat(Elements[3]);
      end;

      SystemCoords.Add(SystemCoord.Key, SystemCoord.Value);
    end;

  finally
    Lines.Free;
    Elements.Free;
  end;

  try
    ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    for SystemCoord in SystemCoords do
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(SystemCoord.Key);
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you that is a lot cleaner code and easier to read, But it doesn't seem to load them into the record any fast than using "pos" which makes it no more economical than original. I am thinking I might have to look at database access to speed this up and reduce loading times, it not a huge loading time but to load the application seamlessly is the goal.  thank you for your contribution